# Could not find a declaration file for module 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'?

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, typescript, npm, material-ui

I'm trying to use the react material-ui theme having installed it from npm, I get the following errors when I include 'import MuiThemeProvider from "material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider";' in boot-client.tsx:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
>   'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'.
>   'W:/web/WebFront/node_modules/material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider.js'
>   implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm install
>   @types/material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider` if it exists or add a new
>   declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module
>   'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';`

I've tried both suggestions to no avail including running the command: npm install -D @types/material-ui.

My @types folder in node_modules exists with the relevant types.

Here is the code where I'm trying to use it:

```
import './css/site.css';
import 'bootstrap';
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import configureStore from './configureStore';
import { ApplicationState }  from './store';
import * as RoutesModule from './routes';
let routes = RoutesModule.routes;


import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';


// Create browser history to use in the Redux store
const baseUrl = document.getElementsByTagName('base')[0].getAttribute('href')!;
const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: baseUrl });

// Get the application-wide store instance, prepopulating with state from the server where available.
const initialState = (window as any).initialReduxState as ApplicationState;
const store = configureStore(history, initialState);

function renderApp() {
    // This code starts up the React app when it runs in a browser. It sets up the routing configuration
    // and injects the app into a DOM element.
    ReactDOM.render(
```

,
            document.getElementById('react-app')
        );
    }

```
renderApp();

// Allow Hot Module Replacement
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./routes', () => {
        routes = require<typeof RoutesModule>('./routes').routes;
        renderApp();
    });
}
```

Comment: please give some code snippets from you App where you are trying to set `MuiThemeProvider`

Comment: done, added some more details too :)

Comment: Do you get the error just by importing it?

Comment: the first error I've quoted is in the browser, the second is on the import.

Comment: You are importing but not using `MuiThemeProvider`. You need to wrap your app with the `MuiThemeProvider ` component

Comment: Using it doesn't make the error go away? I addedit back in to cover appcontainer whichi s what I was doing before not that it changes anything...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I figured it out, in tsconfig.json under 'compilerOptions' visual-studio by default had its types set to ["webpack-env"], I needed to add "material-ui" to it or optionally just remove it: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: Can you elaborate more with the code snippet?

Comment: PLEASE BE MORE CLEAR

Comment: Please add snippet of code to your answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me which is med's answer above which I explain in more detail below.

Open the `tsconfig.json` file. Add `"types":"material-ui",` within `"compilerOptions": {}`

as in

`"compilerOptions": {"types":"material-ui"}`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `default` import from the same path.

`import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider'`